# user.validationcode@domain.com How to do this?

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I'm wondering how I could map an email adress so newsletter users could simply write to a uniquely create email address and instantly get unsubscribed.

ex:

jonh.unsubscribe.sdfg87s544fsdg6@exemple.com

And the key here is that I want it to be instantaneous, I don't want to poll a imap or pop3 account every X seconds.  Is there a way to listen to the inbox?  Thats my main problem...  once I get the email I know what to do.

Thecnologies I use:
Postfix
Python
PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your mail server supports it, what you are looking for is IMAP IDLE (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177)

Otherwise, you would have to poll.

Comment: tjs for your answer, I found a perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

[Mailman](http://www.list.org) does this by redirecting the mail to the program itself (it never goes to a true mailbox).  Since you're using Python on your project, it might be helpful to look at how mailman interacts with mail servers.